# Configurable options - Not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

My configurable product drop downs and options are not showing on the Frontend.
This happened on Friday.  I then had my host restore the database and all was OK. However, after 24 hours of no problems the issue is back again.  It appears to be ALL configurable products. See link below.

Can any one help?  Thanks in advance.
[Example Configurable on site](https://www.hejhog.com/running-hare-t-shirt-bee-eaters-2.html)

Just noticed that the console on Firefox shows the js error ReferenceError: optionsPrice is not defined. I assume this is related.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed you have a Javascript error in your page and most likely that's the reason for your error:

The JS variable `optionsPrice` is defined in line 1070:

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice
```

But you are trying to assign already in line 799 something to `optionsPrice['55107']`:

```
optionsPrice['55107'] = new Product.OptionsPrice({"productId":"55107","priceFormat":...
```

Most likely there is something wrong in your phtml files. The code from line 1070 is out of the standard Magento template `catalog/product/view.phtml` while the other erroneous usages of optionsPrice are not.

I would suggest to look in your phtml files for `new Product.OptionsPrice` and you should find a hint for your error.

I hope that helps a little.

Comment: Cheers.  You got me thinking that it was a conflict of modules.  The irony was that the Amasty troubleshooter "Fix" was causing the issue.  Rolling this back solved the problem.  The strange thing was that the "Fix" was implemented way in the past and I am perplexed as to why this suddenly caused an issue.  I wish I could mark this as the solution but the problem is so unique to my set up that I am not sure if this will help anyone apart from myself.  I am therefore leaving a comment in case I am stupid enough to implement the "fix" again sometime in the future!!